# Can't display ColumnRange chart with highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I would like to integrate a columnrange graph in my asp application. To do that I have copied the official demo (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/columnrange/) in my code but that display an empty graph and I have an error in my console:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'lineWidth' of undefined at highcharts.src.js:18012:44".
```

I only have this error on columnrange type graph, no problem for the other types. I have included highcharts-more.js.
Why I have this error and how to resolve it ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Need more info. What's your code? Put up a fiddle for us to look at that demonstrates the problem, or link to a live example.

Comment: the fiddle I use is the official demo (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/columnrange/).
I have exactly the same code in my app so I can't recreate the same bug. The problem is not from the code.

Comment: If we can't recreate the problem, we can't solve the problem.

Comment: can you please check if the data is  present while creating the chart. ie value in the data : []